# Refresh $scope while in $apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my HTML, I have an element with a `ng-click` attribute to trigger a function. This function contains a loop which calls another function in each step. Now, I would like to refresh my `$scope` after every step of the loop, but:

- I can't use `$scope.$apply` since I'm already inside an `$apply` phase due to the `ng-click`attribute,
- I can't use `onclick` instead of `ng-click` because the click function changes (with `ng-repeat` specifically), and
- `$timeout` doesn't work because it somehow messes the order in which the function inside the loop runs (I guess the click function runs the loop and then the bit inside `$timeout` takes place).

Here's my code:

```
// IN MY HTML
<th class="groupHeader" ng-repeat="j in groupsMain" ng-click="thClickColumn(j)">{{j}}</th>

// IN MY CONTROLLER
$scope.thClickColumn = function(j) {
    // some code
    for ( var i = 1 ; i <= 7 ; i++ ) {
        _this.tdClick(i,j) ; // I'd like my $scope to refresh after doing this
        if ( _this.inputElement === false ) { return ; } // Also, this bit here should break the loop if the condition is met (_this.inputElement is returned by the function above)
    }
} ;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to refresh `$scope` after every step of the loop ?

Comment: Angular continues to do dirty checking and running all the observers, e.g. `$watch`es, till there are no more changes made to the `$scope`. It'll complain if it has to run more than `N` iterations (I think it was 50). Other than that, `$scope` is just a plain old Java object and you should be able to set properties on it in the usual way. Perhaps I am missing what you mean when you say "refresh my `$scope`"?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't express myself correctly (still new in this, sorry). What I mean is I want to update the bindings and see the changes made in my page right after each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you could use `$timeout`, just make sure the promise chain is correct:

```
$scope.thClickColumn = function(j){

     var iterator = 7;

     function call(){
         if(iterator > 0){
             _this.tdClick(iterator, j);
             $timeout(function(){
                 iterator--;
                 if(_this.inputElement !== false){
                     call()
                 }
             })
         }
     }

     call();
}
```

Comment: Cool, I'll try this when I get home. Can you explain how it works, please? :)

Comment: It works perfectly! And now that I can get a real look at it, I see how it operates. So many thanks! :D